# how to fix widget movement when screen size changes?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a problem, I am creating an android app and when I resize the screen, the images are not in the place where they should have been in the background. How to make the images to be in a certain place on the background and when resizing the window to be in the same place on the background but with the changed size.
my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
<RootWidget>
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            id: background
            size:self.size
            nocache: True
            source: 'background.gif'
        Image:
            id: image
            pos:(229, 191)
            size_hint:(None, None)
            size:(320, 180)
            source: 'image.gif'
''')

class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    pass

class WindowApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WindowApp().run()
```

normal screen:

[image: normal screen]

changed screen:

[image: changed screen]

Comment: You've defined your position and size in terms of an exact number of pixels, but it sounds like you want to place it relative to the parent. Try using a `pos_hint: (0.3, 0.5)` instead of a pos, and potentially a `size_hint: (0.2, 0.35)` instead of a size (numbers made up for testing purposes).

Comment: it doesn't work